# Algorithm to verify whether a point is circled

Tags: android, algorithm, geometry, point

[image]

I will have an oval in the plane.The x and y co-ordinates of the center of oval and radius of the oval is known.Using a particle to move around the plane,have to verify whether the oval is circled(by moving the particle through all the sides of the oval).

How can I verify whether the oval is circled by the particle?

Comment: Your question is too broad, I read "I have this idea, tell me all the algorithms and tools I'll need"

Comment: @IvanBartsov - Thanks. I edited the question with appropriate input for the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider centre of oval is (0, 0deg) in polar coordinates.

I am assuming your particle doesn't go inside the boundary of oval(from your words side of oval).

Minimize min and max with start position(atan(yParticle-yOvalCentre, xParticle-xOvalCentre)) of particles. Everytime particles goes towards min update min angle and similar for max. Once max - min > 360, you have completed the circle.

Comment: Could you please brief the answer? After finding the angle with the current position and the centre point of the oval what exactly should we do? I added a image of my application. It is similar to horse barrel game.

Comment: For n ovels and 1 particle, you would keep 2 arrays min_angle and max_angle of size N each. Everytime the point moves, check for each oval the angular change. atan(oldx - oval[k].x, oldy - oval[k].y) v/s [atan](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan/)(newx - oval[k].x, newy - oval[k].y). This the new angle already falls in the range (or min[k] to max[k] segment) do nothing. But if you have moved slight clockwise or anticlockwise from your position, update either min[k] or max[k] by min[k]-deltaAngle or max[k]+deltaAngle. If max[k] - min[k] for any oval crosses 360 degree, you circled k.

Answer (score 1):

When you decided to start painting oval around circle, you created the starting vector from circle center to point (let's call it mouse point).

> (mouseX-circleX, mouseY-circleY) = start vector

So, initial angle between current and starting vector will be 0 (until you move your mouse).

Mohit suggested you to check whether your current vector achieved some delta (359 deg is enough) between minimal and maximal angle value (angle can vary between -180 .. 180).

I'm not sure about his formula, though. I think it's better to find angle between starting vector (ax,ay) and current (bx,by) using the fact that

> [a,b] = |a|*|b|*sin(alpha) = ax*by - ay*bx
>
> (a,b) = |a|*|b|*cos(alpha) = ax*bx + ay*by
>
> atan( [a,b] / (a,b) ) = atan(tan(alpha)) = alpha

So, calculate current angle on every mouse move and update min/max values, until max-min < 359

If you want to check it simultaneously for several circles, do it simultaneously for array of starting vectors and min/max values)

**UPD** I've noted big problem here, after painting 180 degrees around circle you'll achive -180 point immediately. So I think the best thing to do is to accumulate some summary value of signed delta angles between current and prevous "MouseMove" callback. So, when summary value will become 359 or -359 that mean you maked valid clock or counter-clockwise rotation.